# How to change the no data label in the element ui vue 3 table

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I need to change the no data label before making a request to the server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bf5a.png)

I would like to get the inscription "Downloading company data..."

This is a simple question and I do not know what else to add to the description in order to fulfill the requirement for the length of the description of the question "Body must be at least 220 characters; you entered 178."

Answer (score 2):

In the Element Plus documentation, it is explained that you can use the `empty-text` attributes for the Table component to customize the default "No Data" message.

| Attribute | Description | Type | Accepted Values | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| empty-text | Displayed text when data is empty. You can customize this area with `#empty` | string | — | No Data |

```
<el-table empty-text="Downloading company data..."></el-table>
```

Comment: yes this answer is correct